# How to get token sent to a ERC721 contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a ERC721 contract, and my mint method requires 1 ether.
My contract is here:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Example is ERC721 {

    uint256 private _tokenId = 0;

    function mint(uint256 tokenURI, uint256 id) public payable returns(uint256){
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        require(id > 0);
        
        _tokenId += 1;
        _mint(msg.sender, _tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(_tokenId, tokenURI);
        return _tokenId;
    }
}
```

My question is how can I know where that value is stored? On the explorer, I can see there's 1 ether on the contract address, how  can I get the token out? Using balanceOf from ERC721 can only get the number of tokens that an address have. I want to see the values on this contract address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear but it looks like you are not able to get tokens data because your contract does not store any token.

You are missing many basic things in your smart contract. For example where are the tokens stored? I cannot see any array for that. What is the data associated with a token? I cannot see any struct defined.

Once you define how the tokens are stored then you can retrieve their data.

Please note the example below is just to show you a basic implementation and many things have to be defined. If you just copy and paste it then it won't work.

```
YourTokenStruct[] public yourTokens;

struct YourTokenStruct {
    string name;
    uint256 id;
}

function mint(string memory name, uint256 id) public payable returns(uint256){
    require(msg.value == 1 ether);
    require(id > 0);
    
    uint _tokenId = yourTokens.push(YourTokenStruct(name, id)) - 1;

    _mint(msg.sender, _tokenId);

    return _tokenId;
}
```

As you can see the array `yourTokens` stores all tokens created, and the struct `YourTokenStruct` defines the data structure of a token.

I suggest you to follow the tutorial https://cryptozombies.io/ it explains all the basics on how to code ERC721 token standard.

---

EDIT: The ether is stored on the smart contract address (the address where the contract has been deployed). Below an example of a function that transfers the ether from the smart contract to the caller of the function (of course define the modifier `ifOwner` yourself):

```
function withdraw() payable external ifOwner {
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In this contract, when you mint, you have to send 1 ether to the contract, I want to know where this 1 ether is stored and is it possible that as the contract owner to get the 1 ether.

Comment: The ether is stored on the contract address (the address where the contract has been deployed). And yes, you can transfer the amount from the contract address to the owner. For example the function below transfer the amount of ether stored in the contract to the caller (msg.sender) only if the caller is the owner of the contract: 
```function withdraw() payable external ifOwner {
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance); 
}```
- Of course you have to define your `ifOwner` modifier.